# Google sheets is able to access protected sheets and workbook. How to properly protect them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I was making a quiz template on Excel with all the correct answers on a separate sheet so it can be compared and then graded, again in another sheet on the same file/workbook. The two other sheets are hidden and I protected the whole workbook with a password before sending it.

It's from a class and I noticed 1 or 2 submissions had a #REF error on the scoring sheet, upon closer inspection, those weird submissions were able to insert a row or column on the publicly viewed sheet and it disrupted the calculation on the scoring sheet. (I tried it in excel and since all cells are locked except on the one ones I allow them to put their answer, you can't insert a row/column)

How?, I asked myself. So I tried uploading the quiz on google drive and was able to view the hidden sheets and even click on the cells that were protected to see the formulas.

Is there a way to fully protect an excel workbook. One solution I found was to encrypt the whole workbook and this one seem to work against google sheets as it made it read-only. But then, students who don't have Microsoft office purchased/owned won't be able to answer them.

Comment: This doesn't fully solve this question. But I found a workaround for now. I will keep the answers on the separate excel file that I won't distribute, then on the grading sheet on the quiz, I will reference that external file with the answers so even if they can open it on Google sheets, they won't know the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were able to do that, as for myself I've had a **huge** headache trying to access a password-protected sheet and being unable to after my O365 subscription had temporarily run out.  At that time, I had tried uploading and access via G Sheets as well, but was unable to; in fact, it wouldn't even allow *any* password input as to allow access *at all*, I was simply just locked out.  Luckily I was able to find a Linux utility that allowed me to feed a password to it and create an unprotected copy, but I digress!

Back to the point of your use case: I believe you may be overthinking things.  As students, schools *should* be offering O365 Education Edition keys either for free or at a discount (mine is free, but I'm not sure if they all work that way); [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/college-student-pricing) is the current Microsoft web page to this regard.  Even in the case that they aren't doing so due to the institution not qualifying or some other reason, my opinion is that the students or their family/guardians should be expected to supply them.  This is consistent with the convention of families supplying their children with backpacks, pencils, and other such supplies.  Of course, there may be those among students who are under financial duress and aren't able to afford the subscription, but those are exceptional cases, not the rule.

Of course, realistically speaking I understand it may not be reasonable to suddenly make this demand of parents or guardians.  As an alternative, what I can suggest is to separate the worksheets into separate workbooks.  If we are to look at it from the perspective of segregation practices, it makes little to no sense to package the sensitive contents bundled in with what you intend to disseminate, only to attempt to restrict access to just that portion of what you've freely given out.  Speaking speculatively, if you have a student who is exceedingly proficient with computer technologies, they might even be able to break the password protection themselves.  Thus, it would seem to me more prudent to preclude even the possibility of that data being accessed by unintended parties by not sending it out at all.

You can still use references to an external sheet so much of your automation can still presumably be retained (you may have to be creative with your use of data validation to force answers to be in the correct formatting or ranges), and although in most cases you might need to have both workbooks open simultaneously, that shouldn't be a debilitating requirement?  Hope that helps!